# Read environment variable using Macros iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I like to read the environment variable in my header file using macros and assign to LOGGING_ENABLED in following code (instate of static value like 1).

```
#define LOGGING_ENABLED   1
```

Any way to get environment variable using Macros ?

Comment: Environment variables are a run-time feature. Macros are a compile-time one. But anyways, iOS applications don't get any additional environment variables set, so I don't understand how/why this is useful...

Comment: Edited the question, I like to read the environment variable in my header file using macros.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare An environment variable only exists when your app is running.  A Macro only exists when your code is being compiled.  Never the two shall meet.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I think I need to use preprocessor Macros.